# Http requests in electron

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, httprequest, electron

I'm doing a desktop application with electron where I need to make an http request to a php to close the session on the server.

The case is, that the session closes perfectly but the content that is inside http.get (options, function (res) {} does not work, it's like I do not enter here

I leave you the code below

```js
var http = require('http');

var options = {
    host: localStorage.getItem('server'),
    port: localStorage.getItem('port'),
    path: localStorage.getItem('directori') + '?nosession=1&call=ciberFiSessio&numSerie='+ localStorage.getItem("pc")
};

http.get(options, function(res) {
    alert("hola");
    
    if (res.statusCode  == 200) {
        alert("hola");
        //reinicia();

        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            str = chunk;
            alert(str);

            var myJSON = JSON.parse(str);
            //alert(myJSON.fi);

            if (parseInt(myJSON.fi)==0){
                alert("Hi ha hagut un problema!");
            } else {
                reinicia();
            }

        });

    } else {
        alert("El lloc ha caigut!");
        alert(res.statusCode);
    }
}).on('error', function(e) {
    alert("Hi ha un error: " + e.message);
});
```

Comment: use window.alert instead of alert.